# How to get "data" associated with each tab on clicking on it, using Jquery ui - tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jquery-ui tabs. On clicking on the tabs, I want to get the data associated with it. 
I am using knockout foreach binding to show the tabs. 
Giving my code below

```js
var counter = 0;
var ItemViewModel = function(data) {
  counter += 1;
  this.id = 'tab-' + counter.toString();
  this.href = '#tab-' + counter.toString();
  this.tbna = data['tbna'];
  this.text = "text for tab "+ data['tbna'];
  this.query = data['tqry'];
};

this.tabList = ko.observableArray();
var dt = {};
dt.result = [{tbna : 'a', tqry : 'some texts'},{tbna : 'b', tqry : 'some more text'}]

 for(var i in dt['result'])
 {
   this.tabList.push(ItemViewModel(dt['result'][i]));
 }

$( "#tabs").tabs({
  activate: function(event, ui){
    var tabNumber = ui.newTab;

    // I need "query" associated with the tab here, on clicking on tab.
    
    console.log(tabNumber); 
  }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="tabs" data-bind="tabs: { refreshOn: tabList }">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: tabList">
        <li >
            <a data-bind="attr: { title: tbna, href: href }, text: tbna"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div data-bind="foreach: tabList">
        <div data-bind="attr: { id: id }">
            <p data-bind="text: text"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the "query" that I am adding to each tab, on clicking?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your snippet is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something on these lines -

1. Use knockout [click](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) binding on the tabs -

   ```
   <ul data-bind="foreach: tabList">
       <li >
           <a data-bind="attr: { title: tbna, href: href }, text: tbna, click: function(){ $root.someFunction($data); }"></a>
       </li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. Then in your viewModel, define the click event handler, "someFunction" like below -

   ```
   function someFunction(tab) {
       console.log(tab.tqry);
       // Do stuff with the data related to the clicked tab like above.
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.